# Fastest way to transform dataframe to list of lists in R

Tags: r

I frequently need to transform a dataframe to a list of lists. One of the keys is that I need to preserve the types (ie: a number stays a number, string stays a string). This is the function that I use currently:

```
dataframe_to_lists <- function(df){
  return_list <- lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), function(row) as.list(row))
  return(return_list)
}
```

This is accurate but it is not fast when the number of rows grows large (>10K). What is the fastest way to do this in R?

Here is an example:

```
> example_df <- data.frame(col1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'), col2 = c(1, 2, 3), col3 = c(4, 5, 6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> list_result <- dataframe_to_lists(example_df)
> list_result
$`1`
$`1`$col1
[1] "a"
$`1`$col2
[1] 1
$`1`$col3
[1] 4

$`2`
$`2`$col1
[1] "b"
$`2`$col2
[1] 2
$`2`$col3
[1] 5

$`3`
$`3`$col1
[1] "c"
$`3`$col2
[1] 3
$`3`$col3
[1] 6
```

Comment: You could try `nest` from `library(tidyr)`

Comment: simpler : `apply(df,1,as.list)`

Comment: It's critical that the data type is preserved. This is why the `apply(df,1,as.list)` does not work. Numbers get changed to text.

Comment: @HubertL apply turns a df into a matrix, and matrices cannot hold more than one datype.

Comment: Do you need the result exactly as from your function or could it also be something like `lapply(unclass(iris), as.list)`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus I need the same result as my function. I am just creating a list for each row of the dataframe. The names of the elements are the names of the column the data came from. This seems like it should be built into R but I have not found anything that is fast at this.

Comment: Can you make an example for benchmarking? I guess the only improvement on your function is to set all attributes to NULL by reference instead of via as.list.

Comment: @Frank I just added an example

Comment: `do.call(function(...) Map(list,...),df)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
lis <- rapply(df,as.list,how="list")
lis2 <- lapply(1:length(lis[[1]]), function(i) lapply(lis, "[[", i))
```

@A.Webb gave an easier and quicker solution:

```
do.call(function(...) Map(list,...),df)
```

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:10], col2 = 1:10, col3 = rnorm(1:10))

df
   col1 col2       col3
1     a    1 -0.6264538
2     b    2  0.1836433
3     c    3 -0.8356286
4     d    4  1.5952808
5     e    5  0.3295078
6     f    6 -0.8204684
7     g    7  0.4874291
8     h    8  0.7383247
9     i    9  0.5757814
10    j   10 -0.3053884

lis <- rapply(df,as.list,how="list")
lis2 <- lapply(1:length(lis[[1]]), function(i) lapply(lis, "[[", i))

head(lis2, 2)

[[1]]
[[1]]$col1
[1] a
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j

[[1]]$col2
[1] 1

[[1]]$col3
[1] -0.6264538


[[2]]
[[2]]$col1
[1] b
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j

[[2]]$col2
[1] 2

[[2]]$col3
[1] 0.1836433
```

Benchmark:

```
set.seed(123)
N <- 100000
df <- data.frame(col1 = rep("A", N), col2 = 1:N, col3 = rnorm(N)) 

system.time({
    lis <- rapply(df,as.list,how="list")
    lis2 <- lapply(1:length(lis[[1]]), function(i) lapply(lis, "[[", i))
})

user  system elapsed 
1.36    0.00    1.36

system.time(do.call(function(...) Map(list,...),df))

user  system elapsed 
0.69    0.00    0.69
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, it's beautiful.

Comment: Can you shorten `lapply(1:length(lis[[1]]), function(i) lapply(lis, "[[", i))` to `lapply(seq_along(lis[[1]]), lapply, X=lis, FUN="[[")` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Not immediately sure why but that gives me an error. Edit: For completeness' sake: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : incorrect number of subscripts`

Comment: Not quite as fast (though still faster than the original), but simpler: `lapply(seq.int(nrow(df)), function(x){as.list(df[x,])})`

Comment: `do.call(function(...) Map(list,...),df)`

Comment: @A.Webb twice as fast, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @A.Webb : `do.call(Map..` calls for `.mapply`; `.mapply(list, as.list(df), NULL)` :-)

Comment: You may incorporate into yours if you like.